# Invoking org-store-link interactively, errors on calling org-man-store-link

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I encounter issues when calling org-store-link interactively, i.e.

```
helm-M-x-execute-command: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-man-store-link
```

Apparently this is a new behaviour, which has altered before conducting any package updates/upgrades. Debugger would stop here:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-man-store-link)
  org-man-store-link()
  org-store-link(nil 1)
  funcall-interactively(org-store-link nil 1)
  command-execute(org-store-link record)
  helm-M-x-execute-command(org-store-link)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  helm-internal((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x378f185d3fa1c13>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3773604a5243770>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1995426471c9d4e1>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10e73ff112ae1fc2>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  apply(helm-internal ((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x378f185d3fa1c13>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . ...) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3773604a5243770>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1995426471c9d4e1>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . ...) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10e73ff112ae1fc2>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history))
  helm((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x378f185d3fa1c13>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3773604a5243770>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1995426471c9d4e1>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10e73ff112ae1fc2>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  apply(helm ((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x378f185d3fa1c13>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . ...) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3773604a5243770>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1995426471c9d4e1>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . ...) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10e73ff112ae1fc2>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history))
  helm(:sources (((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x378f185d3fa1c13>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3773604a5243770>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1995426471c9d4e1>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46112040>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46171040>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46160040>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46147040>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e46156040>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460d5040>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e460c4040>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461db040>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461ca040>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461a9040>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e461b8040>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x1cc6b6e4613f040>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . undefined) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) (26 . helm-toggle-full-frame) (3 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) (67108987 . helm-enlarge-window) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #f(compiled-function (candidates source) #<bytecode -0x1375fa7292382ecb>) helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10e73ff112ae1fc2>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) :prompt "M-x " :buffer "*helm M-x*" :history helm-M-x-input-history :truncate-lines t)
  helm-M-x-read-extended-command([python-imenu-format-parent-item-label table--measure-max-width org-element-paragraph-separate calendar-forward-week tramp-sudoedit-file-name-handler tramp-completion-handle-file-name-all-completions Set\ Slice ivy-explorer python-nav-beginning-of-defun-regexp Reduce\ To:\ to\ Cc: curr-btn help-follow-symbol treemacs-dom-node->set-position! c-state-min-scan-pos gnus-article-nndoc-name &error rng-parse-validate-file :REVEAL_BACKGROUND_TRANS gnus-mime-security-details-buffer gnus-agent-group-covered-p org-table--descriptor-line edebug-mode-on-hook message-expand-name-databases C-i treemacs--button-symbol-switch nnoo-map-functions smie-config--guess-value search-emacs-glossary kmacro-pop-ring1 which-key--stop-timer c-list-found-types byte-condition-case :mac isqrt 0 About widget-face-sample-face-get nnimap-status-message gnus-summary-limit-to-marks org-agenda-menu-show-matcher nnmail-message-id-cache-file helm-grep-save-results-1 article-fill-long-lines smime-buffer-as-string-region no-truncate check-declare xref-group angle-bracket-arglist-escape bibtex-text-in-string eieio-instance-tracker-child-p ...])
  helm-M-x(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

How can I track/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you fix it? Ensure that the library that defines that function is loaded before you execute code that tries to invoke it - as usual.

Use `require` or any of the other usual ways to load the library from your init file.

See node [Lisp Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html) of the Emacs manual (`C-h r`).

---

@NickD helpfully mentioned in a comment here that the library in question is `org-man.el[c]`. So you can just put `(require 'org-man)` in your init file.

Comment: The library is `org-man.el` in this case, so the invocation is `(require 'org-man)`.

Comment: @NickD: Thx. Added that to the answer.